# nginx PHP won't display

Tags: php, nginx, centos

I have my website stored in /usr/share/nginx/html .gave 777 to all directories and files.when i fire-up the browser and navigate to website, it downloads the page rather than displaying it.
php-fpm is installed and running

this my /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  hostedweb.net;

#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.php index.htm;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
```

}

I'm on CentOS 6
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your `location ~ \.php$ {` try adding `include fastcgi_params;`

Also in your php portion you could try taking out the `root           html;` portion, or try setting it to `root /usr/share/nginx/html;`

Have you tried removing or commenting out `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;`? I don't have that line in any of my nginx config files and they seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding

```
try_files $uri $uri/;
```

To your `location / {}` block

And I believe you don't need this line

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
```

because you included the `fastcgi_params`